# Word 2013 Mail Merge from Excel - send one person duplicate values in mail merge?

Tags: excel, email, ms-word, duplicates, mailmerge

I have a little project going on and I am trying to send many emails to multiple contacts. What I have noticed is that I have multiple values that need to be sent to the same contact, instead of sending multiple emails to the same person I want to modify the value in Word to have more than one. I cannot seem to find the rules to apply it, if it is even possible. I am getting my lists from an excel sheet where I have the name, email address and the multiple client mnemonics.

For example, on the excel sheet:

```
Contact Name    Client Mnemonic Email Address
----------      ----------       ----------  
John Smith      AAAA_12          JS@mail.com
John Smith      AAAB_13          JS@mail.com
John Smith      DGB_34           JS@mail.com

Jane Doe        TILED_EF         JD@mail.com
Jane Doe        RGHF_WE          JD@mail.com
```

I have to send email to these contacts, but do not want to send multiple email to the same recipient. I searched places to apply this but a lot of them did not apply to what I wanted or it was too technical for me to understand.

I looked here:
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154370-Microsoft-Word-Catalogue-Directory-Mailmerge-Tutorial

for the information and a few youtube tutorials, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can advance the mail merge record within a mail merge document but whether that is appropriate for your situation would depend greatly on the nature of your mail merge document. It may be better to 'flat file' your Excel data by reorganizing and moving the AAAB_13 and DGB_34 to the right of AAAA_12.

Comment: But that is not feasible. If you view this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ck8KAwAQso) that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry D. but I don't do ut. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright, thanks again for the information.